# SQLite3 EXCEPT Statement not working as expected

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table containing some information about emails as well as unique IDs for those emails. I want to split off a number of random emails from this table:

```
CREATE VIEW trainview AS SELECT id FROM mails ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1,400;
```

Now I want to split off another few random mails that are not in the "trainview" view:

```
CREATE VIEW helper AS SELECT id FROM mails EXCEPT SELECT id FROM trainview;`
CREATE VIEW testview AS SELECT id FROM helper ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1,200;
```

As I understand it, testview should only consist of IDs that are not in trainview, but:

```
sqlite> SELECT count(testview.id) FROM trainview, testview WHERE testview.id=trainview.id;
18
```

How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, that VIEWS are dynamic and therefore calculated everytime they are used... This leads to different IDs being in the views every time because of the use of random().